# How to Build a Pairwise Ranking Model Using Tree Based Algorithms?

Tags: cart, ranking, boosting

Building a pairwise ranking model using linear algorithms is easy to understand. We just need to do pairwise transformation on the original data and create 0/1 labels. Then feed these pairwise transformed features and labels into a linear algorithm(i.e. LinearSVC) to get model coefficients. Then use predictions output by multiplying the original features with coefficients to do ranking. This [blog post](http://fa.bianp.net/blog/2012/learning-to-rank-with-scikit-learn-the-pairwise-transform/) describes this process well. But obviously we can't use this process for tree-based algorithms such as xgboost. So I wonder what is the algorithm/process used by tree based algorithms to build pairwise ranking models. I understand xgboost has a rank:pairwise option for building pairwise ranking models. My question is about the actual mechanism used for build such models.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "obviously we can't use this process for tree-based algorithms"? I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: I meant you can't plug the original features into a tree model built by pairwise transformed data and use the output predictions for ranking. But we can do this for Linear SVC models.